# How to create GIF stickers from Messages extension

Tags: ios, swift, animated-gif, imessage-extension

I build a **messages app extension**, inspired from the Ice Cream Builder (Apple sample code): https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/IceCreamBuilder/Introduction/Intro.html

Instead using "png" image for my stickers, I want to use animated gif. Because gif are more fun for stickers!

In the sample code, stickers are created from file URL in xcassets folder, with PNG format.

```
func sticker(for mySticker: MySticker, completion: @escaping (_ sticker: MSSticker) -> Void) {

     // Determine the URL for the sticker.
    let fileName = mySticker.name! + ".png" 
    let url = cacheURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    // Create an operation to process the request.
    let operation = BlockOperation {
        // Check if the sticker already exists at the URL.
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        guard !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.absoluteString) else { return }

        // Create the sticker image and write it to disk.
        guard let image = UIImage(named:mySticker.name!), let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else { fatalError("Unable to build image for stickers") }

        do {
            try imageData.write(to: url, options: [.atomicWrite])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to write sticker image to cache: \(error)")
        }
    }

    // Set the operation's completion block to call the request's completion handler.
    operation.completionBlock = {
        do {
            let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "My Sticker")
            completion(sticker)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to write image to cache, error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    // Add the operation to the queue to start the work.
    queue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

I tried to edit filename:

```
let fileName = mySticker.name! + ".gif"
```

...but of course it doesn't work

I noticed animated GIF format works in Xcode only if I create a "Sticker pack" in the xcassets folder.

[image]

But my code doesn't work with it, error to this line :

```
 guard let image = UIImage(named:mySticker.name!), let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else { fatalError("Unable to build image for stickers") }
```

It seems logical, but I don't find a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Use directly the path .gif.
Be careful, if your gif are in a specific folder, this folder must not be a folder reference.

```
func sticker(for mySticker: MySticker, completion: @escaping (_ sticker: MSSticker) -> Void) {

    let fileName = mySticker.name + ".gif"

    let url = cacheURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    // Create an operation to process the request.
    let operation = BlockOperation {

    // Check if the sticker already exists at the URL.
     let fileManager = FileManager.default
     guard !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.absoluteString) else { return }

    // Create the sticker image and write it to disk.
    guard let image = UIImage(named:mySticker.name), let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else { fatalError("Unable to build image \(mySticker.name)") }

        do {
            try imageData.write(to: url, options: [.atomicWrite])

        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to write sticker image \(mySticker.name) to cache: \(error)")
        }
    }


    // Set the operation's completion block to call the request's completion handler.
    operation.completionBlock = {
        do {
            let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "My Sticker")
            completion(sticker)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to write image to cache, error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
struct MySticker {
   var name: String
   var num: Int
}
```